# Python Redirect command output to log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a Python code where I call below Scappy API:

```
sendp(packet, iface=adapter_name)
```

The code works fine but issue is that it prints below line on console where the program is executing as many times the above command is called:

```
Sent 1 packets.                                                                                                         
.
```

I need to suppress the console output so I tried:

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = log_file_name
```

But then I get exception:

```
    sendp(packet, iface=adapter_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 315, in sendp
    verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime, return_packets=return_packets)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 289, in __gen_send
    print("\nSent %i packets." % n)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

How can achieve the objective?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Thanks but I now get on console '.................... '

Comment: You can just use `verbose=0` on your send command to remove the logs... instead of doing a redirection :p

Answer (score 0):

You have this previously answered question if you want to redirect to file:
[Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

The following example for redirecting to a memory string (from python docs):

```py
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    help(pow)
s = f.getvalue()
```

And the latter example (if you just want to suppress the sys.stdout), trying to
understand how it works: print will try to access the `write` method of `sys.stdout`, so I will just replace it with a class that has a write method that does nothing.

```py
>>> class R:
...     def write(*args, **kwargs):
...         pass

>>> from contextlib import redirect_stdout

>>> with redirect_stdout(R()):
...     print('ciao')
```

Comment: I tried the same but now get on console '.................... '  instead of 'Sent 1 packets.                                                                                                         
.'

Comment: Not having your code I will suggest to try to use the context manager for the whole block of code.
Seems that there is a print performed somewhere else.

Comment: Here the raw code output:

>>> sendp(packet, iface='Intel(R) Ethernet Adapter') .    Sent 1 packets.

Comment: Probably scrapy is also writing to stderr.

Comment: I tried also to redirect the stderr, but it does not work.